# Grouping data or clustering data

Tags: time-series, dataset, clustering

[image]I have frame data of 10 subjects gathered from a timeseries analysis. Each subject have 100 frames except the reference frame (timeseries length is 100+1 = 101). Particular frame property is calculated as a percentage. As an example: for subject A, has 60% (61/101 * 100)slow intensity varying fames, 10% medium intensity varying frames, 30% fast intensity varying frames. I would like to group subjects according to “intensity variation of frames”. As an example: out of 10, 4 subjects belongs to the fast intensity group, 3 to slow group. I would like to know what is the best method to group them. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can you upload an example of the dataframe?

Comment: Thank you. I added a photo of the data. Initially I had 4 levels. Later decided to ignore the 4th level. Thank you!